# Scraping Title and Links on the Manage Page of Merch by Amazon using Google Spreadsheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to scrape all the product links and if possible the responding titles. Does anybody know an elegant solution? Is this possible with the importxml function?

[image: Manage Page of Merch by Amazon]

Comment: I might should add that it is a password protected website which requires to log-in to retrieve the data. Maybe this makes the whole process impossible

Comment: What so far you tried add some code so it will be better for understanding!

Comment: Do you have a formula you're working on? And please clarify what URL you are trying to fetch, and what exact data you want to retrieve from there.